How can I force users to update the app? The .apk is a private app, not published on the Play Store
Due to privacy concerns, we can't publish the app on the Play Store. We have kept our .apk file in a secure location, and only users with access to that location can download and use it. I am looking for a strategy to enforce users to update the app when we roll out a new version. We are using React Native Expo to develop our application.
We don't want to send any emails related to new version releases. Instead, we want to enforce users to update the application. Is there a way to do this, or are there any alternative solutions you can suggest?

No. You chose to not use any method of (automated) distribution, so now you can't, at least not without directly telling the people who installed. Why didn't you just use a internal/testing track on Google Play console and use invite links or e-mail invites? Think about it from a safety perspective: wouldn't it be messed up if an app developer was able to update an app completely, over the air, without any kind of security or safetychecks?

@nbokmans thank you for the replay, you mean, no need to publish it and keep my app in google play as Internal testing app right?

Use a pubic web server of your choice, place a file (e.g. JSON) on it containing the information about the latest version available. When starting the app retrieve this file and if it contains info about a newer version then block the UI and inform the user that an update is required.
